# Integrating paytm with cordova/ionic with android 6 support

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I am looking for a paytm plugin to integarate on ionic cordova app. Looked at few options.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-paytm

But this does not support android 6.

https://github.com/samyam-a/PayTM-PhoneGap-Plugin

The above plugin asks for a checksum generation url and checksum validation url. Can someone help with that ? Or is there any better option?